# Is there a way to save an Access Database to a SharePoint folder with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have an Access Database, saved to a SharePoint site, that I maintain for several others to use. A lot of people who use it have been having problems saving to our SharePoint site and I am wondering if there is a way I can create a VBA Macro that would allow them to save their changes to SharePoint just by clicking a control on some form.

What we do now is the standard check out and download the database off of SharePoint and then save our changes over the previous file back in that same SharePoint folder. A lot of the people who use the database don't have a ton of experience with Access in general so I'm looking for anyway to streamline the process as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Access needs an *SMB file share*, which Sharepoint/OneDrive is not (Windows Server and Linux/Samba are).

The only method is, in fact, the one you currently use: Copy the file to a local folder; copy it back when done. Of course, this rules out simultaneous users.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. What I am wondering however is if I can create a macro that can do the "copy it back when done" part for the user automatically upon execution?

Comment: Yes, that could be done. Create a script that copies the file, launches Access and, when this closes, copies the file back. Launch the script from a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with previous comment: Access is not designed to work in this way with SharePoint or OneDrive. Works with SMB. You can manage the DB file, but it is not the best or most efficientway to manage it.

SP Server used to have Access web applications- where you could import an Access solution to SP and it would be converted to a SP app/site. I found them useful to migrate simple Access apps to SP server, and then once as SP apps it was possible to migrate them to SP Online with migration tools. Microsoft dropped them for SP Online a while back (maybe for server too?).

If you are on O365, and it is feasible to consider, then I would  suggest to look into O365 solutions in the longer term, converting or migrating to products like PowerApps, as that is where Microsoft are going in this space.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this is an older post, but perhaps someone finds this answer useful (especially that previous answers are a bit off (at least for the newest version of Access)

My understanding is that you are looking to have an Access application (front-end) that you share with your users and one central database (back-end) where all the data is being stored.

In my experience you certainly can  have the Access database on SharePoint.

There is a Wizard for migrating to Sharepoint in Access (described below).
As a result of running this Wizard, you end up with split database (front-end being your access application) and back-end being SharePoint lists created and populated with your data.

I've worked with this setup with 5-6 concurrent users, and it worked really well.

I use Access for Microsoft 365.

You need to do couple of things first:

1. Have a SharePoint site setup and available
2. Have the SharePoint site url handy. it should look similar to this: (https://YOURCOMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/YOURSITENAME)
3. have your Access DB Compacted and repaired
4. in Access,  click:  Database Tools>Move Data> SharePoint
5. Provide your SharePoint URL
6. Wait. This may take some time, depending on the size of your DB

What the wizard does is it moves all of your access tables into SharePoint lists, and links those lists with your Front-end, so that your application works exactly the same as before. The wizard moves only Tables. Queries, Forms, Reports and any VBA you have is still located in your application.

Hope that helps someone.